# Propagate live updates return promise object instead of value

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

Working on beginner steps toward vue 3 and firestore migration. Stuck on simple.

```
import { getUsersCount } from "/src/firebase";
setup() {
    const usersCount = getUsersCount();

    return {
      usersCount,
    };
  },
```

Why it returns Promise Object, I cant find in manuals.

```
export const getUsersCount = async () => {
    //  const querySnap = await getDocs(query(collection(db, "users")));

    const q = query(collection(db, "users"));
    const unsub = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
        console.log("usersCount33: ", querySnapshot.size);
        //unsub();

        return querySnapshot.size;


    });
  }
```

Nad the last part with template,

```
<template>
  <p>Users Count: {{ usersCount }}</p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you return the value inside a callback, you can not use async await syntax. You should do this:

```js
export const getUsersCount = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "users"));
    const unsub = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      return resolve(querySnapshot.size)
    });
  })
}

// You still need to wait getUsersCount when using it
const usersCount = await getUsersCount();
```

Comment: ERROR: "await" can only be used inside an "async" function

Comment: @EagerToSing Try to follow the error message and fix it. If you still can't figure it out, I will come back with a complete solution. What I want is for you to understand how async/await works.

Comment: I tried until faced router-view and thing become more complicated. Suspense is an experimental feature. Could not make it work.

Comment: @EagerToSing you don't need to use suspense. Just create a wrapper async function and call it in your setup

Comment: somehow template does not update but log showing the change.  async function getCount() {
        
      usersCount = await getUsersCount();
   
       console.log("usersCount is: ", usersCount);
    }

Comment: omg, I managed to do this.   async function getCount() {
      
      usersCount.value = await getUsersCount();
      
    }

Comment: Yeah. Glad you figure it out :)